# How to resolve "MgIndexOutOfRangeException" in MGOS 2.2?

Tags: php, open-source, mapguide

I am working on a GIS based application. I am using the following tools:

1. MapGuide Open Source 2.2
2. MapGuide Maestro 3.5.0.6071
3. Oracle 10g
4. Oracle SQL Developer 3.0.04
5. PHP 5

In MapGuide Meastro, Whenever I add a new **SHP Provider** feature resource and preview it in the browser, it gives the following message:

***Failed to retrieve message for "MgIndexOutOfRangeException". The value is invalid because it is too large.***

However, when I add an **Oracle Provider** feature resource, and preview it in browser, it works fine.

Googling the error message with the above configuration gives **ALMOST 0** useful results. I have posted the same question even the support site, ***osgeo.org***, long ago, but have not received a reply yet.

Does anyone working on these technologies have any idea?

**EDIT**
At least, I have found the root of the problem. It is in

*C:\Program Files\OSGeo\MapGuide\Web\www\schemareport\displayschema.php*

on line: 61

***$firstClass =  substr(strrchr($classCollection->GetItem(0), ":"), 1);***

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by downgrading the MapGuide Maestro from **3.5.0.6071** to **2.1.1.5078**. The interface is not as user-friendly as the latter version, but it resolved not only the problem in question, but some other problems with database connectivity also.

One more drawback, it has no support for composite geometry shapes.

Thanks